# Generating usernames with specific characters in Excel

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to create an Excel formula to generate usernames based on first and last name with additional characters at the end. I want the username to be the first initial of the first name, with up to seven letters of the last name, and then "_", two randomly generated numbers, and "_ex". For example:

```
Robin Carthright --> rcarthri_42_ex

John Patterson --> jpatters_75_ex
```

So far I have been able to do the first part of the formula for generating the first initial and last name, but can't figure out how to add the extra characters in the Excel formula.

Here is what I have now:

```
=LEFT(PROPER(LEFT(A1)&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))),8)
```

Comment: Should the numbers always be 2 characters?

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to include the formula as you have it to this point?

Comment: Check out my update as I corrected to lowercase for the name part of the username.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is my take on it:

[image]

Formula:

```
LEFT(A2,1)&MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)+1,7)&"_"&RANDBETWEEN(10,99)&"_ex"
```

You can change lower and upper in the randbetween().

Edit for lowercase only:

```
LOWER(LEFT(A2,1)&MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)+1,7))&"_"&RANDBETWEEN(10,99)&"_ex"
```